# Grails: How to use executeQuery with embedded object

Tags: grails, hql

I have a object with a embedded child:

```
class Parent {
    Child child

    static embedded  ['child']
}

class Child {
    String name
}
```

And I want to use a executeQuery (because in my real case I can't use a Where query or a create criteria). How can I do that without switching to a criteria ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
Parent.executeQuery("FROM Parent parent WHERE parent.child.name = 'FOO'")
```

**Edit:**

Just noticed, you need to add a static declaration for embedded objects:

```
static embedded  ['child']
```

Maybe that will do the trick...

Comment: Yeah, thats a mistake in my original post, I will fix it